# Is it possible to get a list of all transactions a user has made on paypal?

Tags: paypal

I spent all day playing around with [this API call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#list-payment-resources) thinking I could use Paypal's `Ruby gem` to authorize a user and then use that api call to get a list of any transaction the user has made on paypal recently.

I'm starting to think that call is not made for that but is instead used to see a list of transaction made on your app, is this correct?

Is what I was trying to accomplish in the first place even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is possible. You can search through an accounts transaction history and then collect the details from the one from a particular user.

Searching transaction tutorial for paypal can be found here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_searchRetrieveTransactionData-curl-etc/

I am not sure why you want to use the Ruby Gem  to authorize a user as part of this. All you need to do is search on the EMAIL or NAME fields. 
See here for a list of fields that you can search transactions on: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: I'm not trying to search my transactions, im trying to search the transactions of a random user who logs into my website via paypal

Comment: The request above will search all transactions that that user has made with you. You will not be able to see what other transactions that user has made with other merchants. That would be a huge breach of privacy and the functionality is not provided by the paypal API.